# Is OnResultExecuted() asynchronous? (MVC3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, events, httpcookie

Suppose `OnResultExecuted()` is implemented in `BaseController`.

> Now suppose I have a `View` on which I render **4** `Actions` (each
>   makes one ajaxRequest).

**THE QUESTIONS:**

1.How OnResultExecuted() is executed (in what order)?

2.Is it sync or async?

3.If I delete a cookie in such a manner:

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    // Some checks, that assure the cookie existence.
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);

    //** BREAKPOINT **

    // Create new cookie.
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "my cool encrypted data");
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

-Then what would the browser inspection tool, show at the ** BREAKPOINT **?

-Would the cookie still be alive on the **second** request of those 4 ajax requests (*NOT AT THE END OF PAGE REFRESH*)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Look at MSDN for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onresultexecuted(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is poor, and the phrase 'Called after the action result that is returned by an action method is executed.', seems to me a fruit salad of words :). Nothing personal..